# In Symfony, how do you fill a new column with values related to existing column values?

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine

Let's say I have a database and a table called User, which is filled up all with "name", "age". Name is like "Peter David Smith" or "Adam Pitt". Inside the User entity, I want to create a new column.

```
/**
* @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
*/
private $name;

/**
* @ORM\Column(type="integer")
*/
private $age

// THIS IS THE NEW COLUMN
/**
* @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
*/
private $monogram;
```

How do I tell Doctrine that the new column called "monogram" should be filled up with the first letters of the $name's words? So in the case of "Peter Daniel Smith" it should be "PDS", at "Adam Pitt" -> "AD". The database has a lot or records with "name" and "age" so the database is not empty.

I've tried this in the constructor, doesn't work:

```
public function __construct()
{
    // ...

    $words = explode(" ", $this->name);

    foreach ($words as $w){
       $this->monogram .= $w[0];
    }
}
```

After this I make the migration, run it, but the monogram column is null everywhere.
Is there any way to fill the $monogram based on the existing database data on this level?

Comment: You could have made a custom function within the migration file to do this, looping through all current records and calculating each `$monogram`. When doing `php bin/console make:migration` it will create the migration file, you can add to the `up` method then run `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate` to run it. Then for future insertions you can use `@ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks` in your entity and a method `onPrePersist(){...}` setting the `$monogram` automatically on every insert.

Comment: 1st question: So in the migration file I have to reproduce the same functionality I would do in the onPrePersist function, only with SQL?

Comment: 2nd question: How do I apply the migration file if I have made changes in that: - I suppose - I wrote the SQL that creates the initials (monograms)? @Bossman

Comment: 1) Yes correct. 2) You can create a blank migration class file with `doctrine:migrations:generate` [ref](https://symfony.com/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/current/index.html#usage). Then put the logic in to convert and insert etc..

Comment: Thanks, one last question, in the migration file, how do I iterate through all the records with SQL and set the actual record's initial (monogram) to the record's name's? @Bossman

Comment: I'm not at a computer right now but will try and write up an answer tomorrow for you if no one else answers.. Have a Google in the mean time regarding the migration class.

Comment: [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65357641/access-entity-manager-inside-symfony-5-migration-class) an example for you to work with

Answer (score 1):

First update current records via a migration file. You have already created the *monogram* field.

Create a new migration file with `doctrine:migrations:generate`. This will be located `/migrations/VersionXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.php`.

**Edit your migration file, so it is like this:**

```
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace DoctrineMigrations;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Schema;
use Doctrine\Migrations\AbstractMigration;

/**
 * Auto-generated Migration: Please modify to your needs!
 */
final class VersionXXXXXXXXXXXXXX extends AbstractMigration
{
    public function getDescription(): string
    {
        return '';
    }

    public function up(Schema $schema): void
    {
        foreach ($this->connection->fetchAll('SELECT id, name FROM user') as $user) {
            $this->addSql(
                'UPDATE user SET monogram = :monogram_field WHERE id = :user_id',
                array(
                    'monogram_field' => $this->generateInitials($user['name']),
                    'user_id' => $user['id']
                )
            );
        }
    }

    public function down(Schema $schema): void
    {
        // this down() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs

    }

    private function generateInitials(?string $string): ?string
    {
        if (null === $string || empty($string)) return null;
        
        // Regex to match first letter of each word
        preg_match_all('/(?<=\b)[a-z]/i', $string, $matches);

        return strtoupper(implode('', $matches[0]));
    }
}
```

You can run `doctrine:migrations:migrate` or `migrations:execute --up 'DoctrineMigrations\VersionXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'`  to run it.

**Now for future insertions, update your User entity to include these functions:**

```
/**
 * Gets triggered only on insert
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 */
public function onPrePersist()
{
    $this->monogram = $this->generateInitials($this->name);
}

private function generateInitials(?string $string): ?string
{
    if (null === $string || empty($string)) return null;

    // Regex to match first letter of each word
    preg_match_all('/(?<=\b)[a-z]/i', $string, $matches);

    return strtoupper(implode('', $matches[0]));
}
```

Remember to add `@ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks` to the top of the class. When a new User is inserted it will populate the *monogram* field.

I haven't fully tested this. Test it locally first on dummy data and tweak as you see fit.